# Bootsrap prevents styling on print

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

While printing HTML page all works fine,
After adding bootstrap library all styling disappear on printing.

wrapping css file with @media all {}  not solving the issue.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to see if you add your style sheet after the bootstrap one it may overwrite the styles in the bootstrap file.

Comment: Tried and failed.

Answer (score 0):

Use your bootstrap css cdn in this way--

```
<link ../bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='all'>
```

or

```
 <link ../bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen,print'>
```